# php_Curl installation and use?

Tags: php, curl

I have picked up a quick PHP project that I need the use of the `php_curl` library.

I am having difficulty getting to recognize the library when I used it in my code. I have researched many different ways to install, and use the `php_curl` library, which comes with PHP, but apparently is not enabled.

Can anybody assist me in allowing my php to recognize when I make a simple call such as the following:

```
$ch = curl_init();
```

so that it does not tell me that it does not recognize the function name.

Comment: What operating system is PHP running on? That will make a big difference in how to install curl.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`echo phpinfo()` and find the word curl if curl is not there

By default CURL is not enabled with php You have to enable.

uncomment the line `;extension=php_curl.dll` in php.ini and restart apache

Comment: i have checked the php.ini, the php-development.ini, and php-production.ini, and they all have extension=php_curl.dll uncommented, but it is still not working. I have checked phpinfo(), and I dont see it there.

Comment: Are you sure you edit the right php.ini? do phpinfo() it will show the right php.ini path edit it restart apache

Answer (score 1):

You can test if the extension is available with:

```
if (function_exists("curl_init")) {
    curl_init();
    ...
}
else {
    // include( PEAR Http Request2 )
}
```